# Laravel Select Query and Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I've been trying to perform a multiple table based query on my laravel project and I got it done for a while. Now, I realized I had to add a **paginator** for a better user experience.

The thing is that I want to convert my **SELECT Query** so I can use the paginate method. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT m.created_at as msg_created_at, m.id, m.on_thread_id, u.name, u.user_title, u.user_pic, u.created_at, u.msg_count, m.content, t.thread FROM messages m, users u, threads t WHERE t.id = '.$id.' AND m.thread_id = t.id AND m.creator = u.id ORDER BY m.on_thread_id
```

**$id** is a dynamic value variable based on the user reference.

I need your help Laravel Masters, thank You.

Comment: What does the query look like in your PHP code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: seems like you have to set relations and use `with`, if you want laravel-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like that:

```php
$res = DB::table('messages')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'messages.creator')
    ->join('threads', 'threads.id', '=', 'messages.thread_id')
    ->where('threads.id', $id)
    ->orderBy('messages.on_thread_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Roman for your answer, it helped me much. 
What I finally did:

```
DB::table('messages')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'messages.creator')
            ->join('threads', 'threads.id', '=', 'messages.thread_id')
            ->where('threads.id', $id)
            ->select('messages.created_at as msg_created_at','messages.id','messages.on_thread_id','users.name','users.user_title','users.user_pic','users.created_at as reg_date','users.msg_count','messages.content','threads.thread')
            ->orderBy('messages.on_thread_id')
            ->paginate(25);
```

I transformed the query so I can join multiple tables and get the columns I need and also put an alias on them (As it was giving me problems with the timestamps() when calling them from the view).

Hope this answer helps more people like me :D